# Finding Sum Of The Differences OF MAX and MIN of All Possible Subsets

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a set of elements, how can I find difference between MAX and MIN in all subsets of this list.

Eg:

set =  1 2 3

```
Subset = {1}, max(s)-min(s) = 0.  
Subset = {2}, max(s)-min(s) = 0.
Subset = {3}, max(s)-min(s) = 0.
Subset = {1,2}, max(s)-min(s) = 1.
Subset = {2,3}, max(s)-min(s) = 1.
Subset = {1,3}, max(s)-min(s) = 2.
Subset = {1,2,3}, max(s)-min(s) = 2.

So the output will be 1+1+2+2 = 6
```

Answer (score 17):

Sort the list.

After sorting, the i'th element will be minimum in all (and only) subsets that do not include the i-1 first elements, and does include this element. There are `2^(n-i)` of those (when `i` is 1 based).

Similarly, `i` will be the highest element in each subset that does not include any number after `i`, and do include `i`, and there are `2^(i-1)` such subsets (again, 1 based).

So, after sorting, just iterate, and for each `i` add:

```
arr[i] * (2^(i-1) - 2^(n-i))
```

Effectively adding the sum by `arr[i] * #times_i_is_max`, and reducing it by `arr[i] * #times_i_is_min`

In your example:

```
sorted=1,2,3
1* (2^0 - 2^2) + 2*(2^1 - 2^1) + 3*(2^2 - 2^0) =
1*(-3) + 2*0 + 3*(3) = -3 + 0 + 9 = 6
```

The bottleneck of this algorithm is the sorting, which is `O(nlogn)` - after that, everything is done in linear scan of the array.

Comment: I got the logic know why you are calculating like this.and this is possible because of commutative property of addition.Dude Your are Intelligent

Comment: if the questiona ask to do with %M then how should the negative should be handled??

Comment: The same way a negative is always handled with `%M`.

Comment: @amit  instead of array , if we take map , i think the it will be faster because map stores them in sorted order.. am i right? just a doubt..

Comment: @polasairam You are going to need to sort it anyway, populating the elements to a map will also be `O(nlogn)`. The constants on a map will be worse however, since array is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

@mukul
you can calculate all powers of 2 and store them in an array taking mod simultaneously 
like

```
a[0]=1; for(i=1;i<any_no;i++)a[i]=(a[i-1]*2)%MOD;
```